# What does `:#?` means in rust format

Tags: rust

```rs
format!("{:#?}", (100, 200));     // => "(
                                  //       100,
                                  //       200,
                                  //     )"
```

Any docs to elaborate on this pattern `{:#?}`?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#sign0

Comment: I don't know about other people, but I call it "fancy".

Answer (score 6):

`?` means a debug format (use [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) and not [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.Display.html)), `#` means pretty-printing the debug format. For example:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct S {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let v = S { a: 1, b: 2 };
    println!("{v:?}");
    println!("{v:#?}");
}
```

Prints ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=070a70e9cd1f63c150fe49fb594ceb8e)):

```
S { a: 1, b: 2 }
S {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
}
```

See [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/#sign0).